# Problema com a resposta do servidor ao montar gráficos

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, servidor

Tenho um dashboard com 8 telas que fazem requisição ao BD. O arquivo principal onde elas ficam (página inicial) faz as requisições com o `load()` do jQuery.
Nos arquivos de telas individuais, cada deles um faz uma pesquisa no BD e a maioria acompanhada de cálculos.

Porém, na maioria das vezes funciona (com a ajuda de cache as vezes), recebo um erro no console assim:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

Ainda não entendo o motivo, ainda sou nova em PHP, apenas sei o básico.

- Qual será o principal motivo do problema?
- O código ou algo relacionado ao servidor?

Segue um exemplo de como está sendo feito:

```
// Arquivo PHP inicial

/*
 * PHP + HTML
 */

<script>
    $('#tela-01').load('path/tela01.php', function(){
        $('.wait').fadeOut(500); // Remove o carregando
    });

    $('#tela-02').load('path/tela02.php', function(){
        $('.wait').fadeOut(500); // Remove o carregando
    });

    $('#tela-03').load('path/tela03.php', function(){
        $('.wait').fadeOut(500); // Remove o carregando
    });

    $('#tela-04').load('path/tela04.php', function(){
        $('.wait').fadeOut(500); // Remove o carregando
    });
</script>
```

Acima um exemplo de como são chamadas as telas.

```
// Arquivo individual

/*
 * Outras Funções PHP
 */

$variavel = $pdo->execute('SELECT campo01, campo02 FROM tabela01 LEFT JOIN tabela02 ON campo01 = campo03 AND campo02 = campo04 WHERE campo00 = 1 ORDER BY campo01');

/*
 * Cálculos de acordo com a pesquisa
 * HTML + PHP
 */

<script>
    (function ($) {
        // Colocando os valores em gráfico e/ou valores nos devidos lugares
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Acima um exemplo de como está os arquivos que exibem os dados. Estes fazem busca no BD e salvam os valores em variáveis para o JS colocar depois ou montar os gráficos (chart.js).

Espero ter representado bem o código.

Comment: Pelo visto vc está fechando a query no meio, após `campo03`.

Comment: Ah não, foi erro meu de digitação mesmo, perdão.

Comment: Acesse o arquivo de log do seu servidor, lá terá a mensagem de erro detalhada.